# Looping thought a javascript / JQuery array and getting a 'grand' total

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok, I have been working on this for some time, I have some close to getting it to work but not completely. So what I am doing is adding the value from a weekly input form into an array with its key.

There will be no limit on the number of rows as I can (and this works fine) AJAX add a row to the form with a button.

I currently add all the totals for each day together, this works, as all the Mondays have a .Monday class on them (I can post that code it need, please just ask) and each other day.

I have also got an id on each input which as the day of the week and a count, so #Monday0, #Monday1, same for each day and each row ect.

Now what I am doing with the code below, is to add the week up and then display that (console log for now) in that weeks row. So I want to add all the daily ids, Monday though to Sunday that end in 0, then do the same for 1 and so on.

```
 var LoadHourTotals = function() {

    $('.TimebreakdownInput').change(function() {
       var InputArrays = []; //Array to store all weekly inputs
       var Totals = []; //Store Array total for display

       GetCurrentID = $(this).attr('id');
       CurrentCount = GetCurrentID.charAt(GetCurrentID.length-1)    
       var WeeklyArray = ["Monday"+CurrentCount,"Tuesday"+CurrentCount,"Wednesday"+CurrentCount,"Thursday"+CurrentCount,"Friday"+CurrentCount,"Saturday"+CurrentCount,"Sunday"+CurrentCount];

        $.each(WeeklyArray, function(k, v) {
            var values = parseFloat( $('#'+v).val() );  
            if (isNaN(values)) { values = 0; } //Set value to 0 if its not a number
            if (!values) { values = 0; }

            InputArrays.push({ key: CurrentCount, hours:values });
        });

        console.log(InputArrays);

        //$('.TimebreakdownTotalHours').html(Totals); //Display / Add total into HTML
    });
} //End of LoadHourTotals function
```

I think I am close with this, each daily input is saved into its own array with a key count and its value for that day. For example, 0:XX 0:XX (this seven times, all for the 1st row). This is then repeated for each row as needed.

If what I have done is not right or there is a better method for doing this, then please let me know.

But now what I need to do is go though each key, take its value, getting a 'grand' total for all seven inputs, then display or save that total into a new array (which is what I was trying to do) then display / console log each weekly total.

I have gone though a number of posts on here but I could not find anything that fits for my problem.

All help very welcome.

If I have not posted some code that is need then please let me know. 
Please let me know if I have not explained myself right.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have not set up a JS fiddle for this, most the form code is not HTML but generated by CakePHP's form helper

Comment: You could copy the html from view source in the browser.

Comment: Yet in your browser it is **pure HTML**  :)

Comment: I could, yes but there is AJAX functions that will not work, and I only just thought about setting one up after I posted - sorry...

Comment: Surely you can just loop through `$.each` of `InputArrays` adding the totals and then storing that in another globally scoped variable which you can access from the other iterations/code and then process that accordingly too?

Comment: Also you are perhaps better off using a data attribute (http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `GetCurrentID = $(this).attr('id');` which would then allow you to forget the `CurrentCount = GetCurrentID.charAt(GetCurrentID.length-1)` parsing and to get the 'latest' id you could then get the `data attribute` f the last object returned by `$('.TimebreakdownInput')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ok, I have found an answer. I tried this but it did not work,

```
 var total = 0;
 $.each(InputArrays,function() {
        total += this;
        console.log(total);
 });
```

But some playing around with the code, I console loged 'this' and tried the following which now seems to work. Thanks

```
var total = 0;
$.each(InputArrays,function() {
    total += this.hours;
    console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: By the way, if you're working in a modern browser you can just [`InputArrays.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or even better, [`InputArrays.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)